# Querying sidekiq for models queued

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have a gallery with photos, on which processing photos is through sidekiq.

When a gallery has photos that are processing or in queue, I'd like to write something in the page.

one option for this is to mark each photo with `processing` when it is added to the queue, and let sidekiq worker remove that when finished. The downside is that I need to check if at least one photo is processing, meaning check all photos...

Is there a way to query sidekiq directly?

Comment: "meaning check all photos" - what do you mean? You're displaying the images, so you load them anyway. Also, "`select count(id) from photos where processing=1`" is a trivial query in every sql db (and will be very fast if supported by index on `processing`)

Comment: Sergio's is the correct answer.  Use the database to store the state of each photo and have Sidekiq update the state.

Comment: if @MikePerham says it, I must listen. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [sidekiq-status](https://github.com/utgarda/sidekiq-status) gem to track your jobs. You can then use code like `Sidekiq::Status::working?  job_id` to check if a specific job is running.